# How does a Paladin's Detect Evil Ability work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin

Can a paladin's **Detect Evil** ability detect if there is Evil in the area, as per the spell, or is it target-only?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the Core rules pdf (pg 60):

> Detect Evil (Sp): At will, a paladin can use detect evil, as the
>   spell. A paladin can, as a move action, concentrate on a single item
>   or individual within 60 feet and determine if it is evil, learning the
>   strength of its aura as if having studied it for 3 rounds. While
>   focusing on one individual or object, the paladin does not detect evil
>   in any other object or individual within range.

In the Detect Evil spell it lists a Cone shaped area effect. So my reading of that is that the paladin can do either but not both at the same time. For example a paladin could be talking to three npc's and use the area effect to see if any of them are evil and then after that move is completed on their next movement action focus on one individual to get a full aura reading but then he would stop detecting evil in the area and only focus on that one npc.

Of course it doesn't seem totally clear cut from the rules explanation so individual players/DM may interpret the rule differently.

Comment: And here's a bonus link to the rules text on the online Pathfinder SRD.  http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin#TOC-Detect-Evil-Sp-

Comment: So is the /as spell/ a full round action as well?

Comment: Yes, its a full round either way, target or cone.

Comment: @BBlake Um, neither version is a full round action. The cone version is a standard action, since it's as per the spell. The targeted version is a move action, as it says in the ability description, shown above.

Answer (score 13):

The description on page 60 of the core rules suggests that it does *both*.

- At will, you can *detect evil* as per the spell.
- As a move action, you can concentrate on a single item or individual and learn the strength of its aura immediately as if you had studied it under *detect evil* for three rounds. While doing this, you don't detect evil on anything else in range.